# LDAP connection problem

Tags: iis, ssl, ldap

We have an IIS server that is not part of the domain that is trying to authenticate a user via LDAP using SSL.  LDAP is on Active Directory.  It seems like the IIS server is having trouble with the LDAP server because it cannot verify the authenticity of it.  How do we go about getting the AD's certificate recognized?

Edit: I added the CA as a trusted root certification authority and that did not seem to make any difference.

Comment: Care to share *why* the IIS server is not in the domain?  It sounds interesting.

Comment: How did you verify that the CA addition went through? My experience is that SSL tools are downright hostile. Also, what are the error messages, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If it's not in a domain, it's not going to trust the domain CA like it would if it were in the domain (assuming you created your own CA). Just install the CA cert on the workgroup server as a trusted CA and you should be good to go.